# Alter column type from json to another

Tags: php, mysql, json, cakephp

I have been sent a file with a site in cakephp 3, with the database and all the files... When i try to create a localhost with these files ( after config all the settings ) i got the welcome screen of cakephp, not the screen of the site that have been developed... It loads all the modules and connects to the database.

When i was importing the database i got an error because of the field type was json, and my mysql is older than 5.7 so it doesn't have that type of field, i changed it to text and the import was successful but the site it's not working... ( loads the welcome screen)

The final server has a mysql 5.6, so it doesn't have the json type also...

I think that the problem is with the json type of field and how i changed it to text ( so that's why it shows the welcome screen ). I have tried to update my local mysql server ( with no success) but the final server can't be updated so that's not the solution.

So, How can i find the problem and get the site to work?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Or you rewrite all the JSON based accessing query  .managing the text as JSON (not easy) . or you looking for a 5.7  database

Comment: No error display or logs or something?

Comment: No errors on the page. With the chrome inspector, in the cosole view, appear several 404 not found in files like webroot/*.css and so....        

`base.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)          
cake.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)        
home.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)        
cake.logo.svg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)        
...        `

Comment: Had to change the database, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to update the final server and change the database to 5.7, and that solved the problem.